# C# get children from JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization

my JSON looks like this:

```
 {
   "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/TOPzMxlQJUtRJBXHeKYMXsdEkHs\"",
   "pageInfo": 
   {
     "totalResults": 1,
     "resultsPerPage": 1
   },
   "items": 
     [
       {
         "kind": "youtube#video",
         "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/BIVqr1Mkbule8othzWvZRor92wU\"",
         "id": "QMNkWwq6L4Q",
         "contentDetails": 
         {
           "duration": "PT4M45S",
           "dimension": "2d",
           "definition": "hd",
           "caption": "false",
           "licensedContent": true,
           "projection": "rectangular"
         }
       }
     ]
}
```

The formatting might be a bit off, sorry.
I tried creating a class like this:

```
public class VideoDetails
{
    public string kind;
    public string etag;
    public string id;
    public string duration;
    public string definition;
    public string caption;
    public string licensedContent;
    public string projection;
}
```

After that I deserialize the JSON file:

```
VideoDetailRead = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoDetails>(json);
```

but I only get "etag" and "kind". Nothing else. My question is: How do I read the data that's listed under "items"? This is my first time working with JSON and therefor I don't know much. Thanks for some answers.

Comment: You can paste json here http://json2csharp.com/ and generate c# classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second object to model the children data. Provided the `items` property has also a child under `contentDetails`, you will also need another object to deserialize these properties.

```
public class VideoDetailsItem
{
     public string kind;
     public string etag;
     public string id;
     public VideoContentDetails contentDetails;
}

public class VideoContentDetails
{
     public string duration;
     public string definition;
     public string caption;
     public bool licensedContent;
     public string projection;
}
```

And to the parent object add a `List<VideoDetailsItem>`.

```
public class VideoDetails
{
    public string kind;
    public string etag;
    public List<VideoDetailsItem> items;
}
```

When deserializing JSON objects you have to **mimic** the JSON object structure in your object. Also, consider using properties instead of public fields to favor encapsulation in your data objects.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks so much. I will remember your hints.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you have listed are inside an array named `items`, so your object hierarchy has to match this:

```
public class VideoList
{
    public string kind;
    public string etag;
    // etc...
    public List<VideoDetails> items;
}

public class VideoDetails
{
    public string kind;
    public string etag;
    public string id;
    public string duration;
    public string definition;
    public string caption;
    public string licensedContent;
    public string projection;
}
```

Then:

```
var videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoList>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't properly modeling the object structure. Right now, your JSON is structured like:

```
{baseInformation, VideoDetailsArray}
```

Thus you have to restructure your data object as

```
public class VideoDetails 
{
    //Base information
    public string kind {get; set;}
    public string etag {get; set;}
    //...
    public List<VideoDetails> {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your class to match the structure of the JSON: in this case, you would define `items` as a list of a separate class which has the properties under it like `duration` etc. You should have your `VideoDetails` class nested inside another class that can wrap both objects in the JSON, and add another class for the `contentDetails` object.

One thing you can do is copy the JSON into your clipboard, open a new class file in Visual Studio, and go to `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON as Classes`. This will create the correct structure for you, and you can see how the nested classes in the JSON properly translate to C# classes.